# The command to start not started init scripts of the current run-level? Gentoo Linux

Tags: linux, gentoo

For example:

`nginx` and `php-cgi` are in the defaults run level, and they are not started yet.

What's the command to start them all, instead of starting then individually?

I know there is a command, but I totally forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

You may run this command as root:

`# rc`

That should do the trick. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `rc-config` + `rc-status` is an answer, with some shell scripting.  Running

```
rc-config list default
```

lists all the scripts in the runlevel `default`. On the other hand, it uses colors and can mess things up, so an alternative app, `rc-status`, does the trick:

```
rc-status -nc default
```

shows all services from runlevel `default` without colors. We'll `awk` from this:

```
rc-config start `rc-status -nc default | awk -v ORS=" " '/^ .+\[ stopped  ]$/{print $1}'`
```

The regular expression pattern takes care that the entry must begin with a space, and end with "`[ stopped  ]`". When run with some stopped services, the oneliner does what you want. If there aren't any, `rc-config` gives a simple syntax error, nothing happens.

I know this wasn't what you wanted, a single command, but it's easily wrapped in a script if you need it often! The programs lie in packages `equery` and `baselayout` so they should exist in every Gentoo installation.